# Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute import

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, inheritance

So I'm new to using asp.net with VB.NET and I'm running into this error:

> Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  Imports System.Data.SQLite
>
> Line 2:  Imports System.Diagnostics
>
> Source File: C:\Projects\HousingInfo\HousingInfo\SQLiteDatabase.aspx.vb    Line: 1

I believe from all my googling that it has something to do with this line:

`<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="SQLiteDatabase.aspx.vb" Inherits="SQLiteDatabase" %>`

This is the code for the database:

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class SQLiteDatabase
Private Shared dbConnection As String

Public Sub New()
    dbConnection = "Data Source=housingInfo.db"
    CreateTables()
End Sub

Public Sub New(file)
    dbConnection = String.Format("Data Source={0}", file)
    CreateTables()
End Sub

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function CreateTables()
    Debug.WriteLine("Creating Tables")
    Dim connection = New SQLiteConnection(dbConnection)
    connection.Open()
    Try
        Dim stm As String = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS houses(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, address TEXT, city TEXT, state TEXT, rented INTEGER)"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can't create table: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
End Class
```

I'm confused. Can I not have import statements in my code?

Comment: You are not inheriting the Page or UserControl -class, just as the error message states. Add Inherits Page to your class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET "pages" must inherit from either `Page`, `UserControl`, or a class that inherits from one of those at some point in the hierarchy.  you are "inheriting" the `SQLiteDatabase` class, which is neither a `Page` nor a `UserControl`.

Typically this is done for you by the designer, so either you're writing everything from scratch or you've changed the markup to inherit from a different class.

Comment: I've add `Inherits Page` to my .aspx.vb file but for some reason I still cannot get the client to call server side. Here's the javascript snippet:

<script type='text/javascript'>
        function CreateTables() {
            PageMethods.CreateTables();
        }
    </script>

Comment: @MichaelWang Do you not have a code-behind class that inherits from `Page` that has the `CreateTables` method defined?  Sounds like you're either trying to learn on your own or following a bad tutorial.  You shouldn't have to monkey with the `Inherits` tag at all unless you know what you're doing.